# Reading files synchronously

Tags: spring-integration

We have the below use case that we are trying to implement:

1. The sender posts a message in JMS queue.  The payload has the name of a file.
2. We need to read the file (file name as provided in the JMS message) from a pre-configured directory and store the contents in database.

Is there any spring component available in file 'namespace' that allows us to read file rather than polling for a file?

I know that we can poll for the pre-configured directory, however we want to see if synchronous read (Sync Read option allows us to read the file from the middle of the process, this is different from the Read option which polls for the new files and is the start of the process) provided by a Oracle Product is also available in Spring Integration.

Comment: What can this question possibly mean?  How can you "poll for" the contents of a file if you don't know the name of the file?

Comment: My question is :  When provided with a filename; what component of spring integration allows me to read a file mid-process

Comment: Yes, I got it. How about to look into my answer?

Comment: @Artem .. I was actually responding to Bruce.   Your answer works like a charm.. Thanks

Comment: Great! I just wanted to let to Bruce to know that there may be someone who doesn't need any additional info. But eh, it would be better really to form questions properly: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Recently I stopped to edit some unclear questions. It takes so much time to figure out an answer otherwise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action to create `File` by its name is so simply that we just didn't introduce some component on the matter.

Here it is:

```
<transformer expression="new java.io.File(payload)"/>
```

or Java DSL variant:

```
.<String, File>transform(File::new)
```

After that you can use out-of-the-box transformers (an `AbstractFilePayloadTransformer` implementation) to get a content and send to DB.

Right, a SpEL expression and Lambda you can customize on your own to build a proper file path based on the preconfigured directory and incoming name.